# Delphi to C# - soFromBeginning

Tags: c#, delphi, porting, glscene

I am writing a port from delphi to c# but i am stuck with this.
soFromBeginning?

```
FStream.Seek(FHeader.DirOffset, soFromBeginning);
```

soFromBeginning isnt support by c# what can i use as a replacement in a Stream?
it seems that soFromBeginning is something in the delphi compiler to accommodate for bigger file sizes or something, not sure.

Porting the GLvfsPack from GLScene to c#

Comment: Guessing that soFromBeginning is "Seek-Origin-FromBeginning". The equivalent in .NET `SeekOrigin.Begin`

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TStream.Seek  -->  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  (also : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/883dhyx0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Gotta love the documentation.

Comment: Where did you read that that identifier has something to do with large files?

Comment: Not sure, in my attempt to find a solution somewhere, i came accross the line, that stated that it had something to do with the 4GB limit or something

Comment: @TheodorSolbjørg Very old Delphi `TStream` implementations only had `Seek` with 32 bit offset parameters. You had to use multiple `Seek` from current position to handle large files. Not a lot of fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the [`Stream.Seek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx) method passing [`SeekOrigin.Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/883dhyx0.aspx).

The seek origin is nothing to do with handling large files. It merely specifies how the offset parameter is to be interpreted. Either relative to the start of the file, relative to the end, or relative to the current position.